# Why is "ALL" breaking my query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the Error I am receiving.

Error Details:

> Parsing of SQL query failed. Please check the SQL syntax. Some tips:
>   Parse error at line 58, column 1.  Encountered: ALL (This "ALL" is the
>   one immediately past the closed parenthesis.)

Here is my query.

```
SELECT  ALL "TR-ID" .   "TR-ID" ,   "Site List Data"    .   "TR-ID",
                                "Issue number from Issue Log",
                        "Project Risks" .   
                                "Suvey Docs/Photos Uploaded to WS Repo",
                        "IPACK" .   
                                "Submit for MIROR code",
                        "Forecasts" .   
                                 "Equipment Ordered Planned",
                                 "Calix Blocker"
FROM                                
(SELECT         "TR-ID"     FROM        "Site List Data"        UNION
SELECT      "TR-ID"     FROM        "Project Risks"     UNION
SELECT      "TR-ID"     FROM        "IPACK"     UNION
SELECT      "TR-ID"     FROM        "Forecasts")        
ALL     "TR-ID"                     LEFT OUTER JOIN
"Site List Data"    ON ALL IDS. "TR-ID" =   "Site List Data"    .   "TR-ID"     LEFT OUTER JOIN
"Project Risks" ON ALL IDS. "TR-ID" =   "Project Risks" .   "TR-ID"     
LEFT OUTER JOIN
"IPACK" ON ALL IDS. "TR-ID" =   "IPACK" .   "TR-ID"     
LEFT OUTER JOIN
"Forecasts" ON ALL IDS. "TR-ID" =   "Forecasts" .   "TR-ID"
```

Comment: This is not MySQL.

Comment: Why do you think you need it in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the `all` keyword right after the `select`, you must not repeat it after every joined table. But you do not need the all keyword at all.

Answer (score 0):

All is a keyword in mysql.

I think you are just trying to alias your sub query, thus the space is the problem. I recommend wrapping names with spaces in square brackets (and remove the quotes) e.g. [ALL TR-IDS].

You've also used 2 different names: ALL TR-ID and ALL IDS. Try this:

```
SELECT [ALL TR-IDS].[TR-ID], [Site List Data].[TR-ID], [Issue number from Issue Log], [Project Risks].[Suvey Docs/Photos Uploaded to WS Repo], IPACK.[Submit for MIROR code], Forecasts.[Equipment Ordered Planned], [Calix Blocker] FROM
(SELECT [TR-ID] FROM [Site List Data] UNION SELECT [TR-ID] FROM [Project Risks] UNION SELECT [TR-ID] FROM IPACK UNION SELECT [TR-ID] FROM Forecasts) [ALL TR-IDS] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Site List Data] ON [ALL TR-IDS].[TR-ID] = [Site List Data].[TR-ID] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Project Risks] ON [ALL TR-IDS].[TR-ID] = [Project Risks].[TR-ID] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN IPACK ON [ALL TR-IDS].[TR-ID] = IPACK.[TR-ID] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Forecasts ON [ALL TR-IDS].[TR-ID] = Forecasts.[TR-ID]
```

Comment: Note: Your second column can only be identical to the first column, or null (if site list data doesn't contain that id). If it's null, all other columns from site list data will also be null.

Answer (score 0):

"select all" is a valid command, but "all" is the default and assumed if not given (i.e. "select all" or "select distinct" are both valid, using "select" by itself is the same as "select all")

Because "all" is used in SQL command you should avoid it for names. Also in MySQL use backticks not double quotes like this:

```
SELECT
      `ALL_TR_IDS`.`TR-ID`
    , `Site List Data`.`TR-ID`
    , `Issue number from Issue Log`
    , `Project Risks`.`Suvey Docs/Photos Uploaded to WS Repo`
    , IPACK.`Submit for MIROR code`
    , Forecasts.`Equipment Ordered Planned`
    , `Calix Blocker`
FROM (
      SELECT
            `TR-ID`
      FROM `Site List Data`
      UNION
            SELECT
                  `TR-ID`
            FROM `Project Risks`
      UNION
            SELECT
                  `TR-ID`
            FROM IPACK
      UNION
            SELECT
                  `TR-ID`
            FROM Forecasts
) `ALL_TR_IDS`
      LEFT OUTER JOIN `Site List Data` ON `ALL_TR_IDS`.`TR-ID` = `Site List Data`.`TR-ID`
      LEFT OUTER JOIN `Project Risks` ON `ALL_TR_IDS`.`TR-ID` = `Project Risks`.`TR-ID`
      LEFT OUTER JOIN IPACK ON `ALL_TR_IDS`.`TR-ID` = IPACK.`TR-ID`
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Forecasts ON `ALL_TR_IDS`.`TR-ID` = Forecasts.`TR-ID`
```

ps: It would make your SQL life way easier if you stopped using spaces in names.